# jQuery function not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a basic "scroll to top" jQuery function for use on my site.  This function works as I would like in Chrome, Opera, and IE though not in my Firefox (37.0.2).

The function is as follows:

```
function scrollUp(){
    $("#to-top").hide();

    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(){
        var num = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (num > 100){
            $("#to-top").show(500);
        };
        if (num < 100){
            $("#to-top").hide();
        };

        $("#to-top").click(function(){
            $("#to-top").hide();
            $('body,html').stop().animate({scrollTop:0},1200);
        });
    });
}

scrollUp();
```

I have checked the inspect element boxes in Firefox but no errors are appearing.

For this to work the HTML is:

```
<a id="to-top">
    <center><p>^ ^ ^</p><p>Scroll To Top</p></center>
</a>
<script src="../scripts/toTop.js">scrollUp()</script>
```

located at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

The HTML is not showing anything in firefox which means that the first line of the jQ function must be working, though for some reason after that it doesn't.

I originally had .on() instead of .bind() they functioned the same in the other browsers buy not firefox....

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: did you scroll down with the mousewheel? Also you should rather bind with `.on` (`.bind` is being deprecated)

Comment: ok changed back to ".on", I've tried the mousewheel, trackpad and arrow keys just there.....nothing in firefox again

Comment: are you 101% sure that the `id="to-top"` is UNIQUE in that page?

Comment: 100% as I say it works seemlessly in other browsers but firefox doesnt carry it out......no errors flagged in the inspect element part either

Comment: make an `alert` when `$("#to-top")` is clcked. does it alert?

Comment: The browser compatibility for mouse wheel event is extremely poor. [Check MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent).

Comment: ok it turns out that was the problem, the 'mousewheel' part.....as stated in the question below 'scroll' gets the job done!!! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `scroll` event and bind using `.on`

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () { /* your mousewheel code here */ });
```

If memory serves, Firefox doesn't like the `mousewheel` event. I'm pretty sure the `scroll` event should work though.

Also, you don't need to run `$(window).bind` every time you `scrollUp()`. That only needs to be done on `$(document).ready`